# change redux state before redirect to user profile

Tags: reactjs, redirect, redux, react-router-dom, history

Hi everyone in my app I have two kinds of users :type A and type B, which can navigate to their profile by clicking on their profile card on HomePage. (user/:name)
After they clicked on the profile card based on their type they will see ProfileTypeA or ProfileTypeB component.
I also have a redux state named profile which contains name and type of the profile user.

the code is as bellow :
user Page:

---

```
    const UserPage=(currentProfile)=>{
    
    return(  
        currentProfile.type===1?
        <ProfileA/>
        :
        <ProfileB/>    
   )}

    const mapStateToProps=state=>({
    currentProfile:state.profile.currentProfile
    })



     export default connect(mapStateToProps,null)(UserPage);
```

---

profile Card Component:

---

```
const ProfileCard=({picUrl,profile,EnterProfile,history})=>{
     const handleProfile=()=>{
     EnterProfile(profile);
     history.push(`/user/${profile.name}`)
     }

    return(
      <Card onClick={handleProfile()}>
        <BgImg bgUrl={picUrl} className='bgImg'></BgImg>
        <NameBox className='name'>{profile.name}</NameBox>
     </Card>
    )}
   const mapDispatchToProps=dispatch=>({
   EnterProfile:profile=>dispatch(EnterProfile(profile))
  })
     export default withRouter(connect(null,mapDispatchToProps)(ProfileCard));
```

---

the problem is that I want to change the "profile" redux state before navigating , in handleProfile function, but the state remains the same .
how should I solve this problem?
thanks in advance

Comment: you may want to try something like `EnterProfile(profile).then((newProfile) => history.push('/user/${newProfile.name}'))`

Comment: it throws an error : EnterProfile(...).then is not a function